# Is it possible to configure database or model root paths?

Tags: ember.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, emberfire

**TL;DR**: When using Firebase with Ember through EmberFire, Is there a way to define the root location where changes should be saved in the firebase database, either for the entire ember instance, or on a per-model basis?

Example: given a `secret` model, which by default would store a new `secret` in `/secrets/<secret GUID>/`, could we configure EmberFire to instead use a sub-path as the root, so a new secret would be created at: `/<some_path>/secrets/<secret GUID>/`?

---

Suppose we have a firebase database configured to support multiple versions of an app during development:

```json
{
  "versions" : {
    "0_0_1" : {
      "isActive" : true
    },
    "0_0_2" : {
      "isActive" : false
    }
  }
}
```

And this `secret.js` model:

```js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  content     : DS.attr('string', { defaultValue() { return "UNDEFINED"; } }),
});
```

By default, when saving a new secret object, a 'secrets' section is created at the root of the database:

```json
{
  "versions" : {
    "0_0_1" : { ... },
    "0_0_2" : { ... }
  },
  "secrets" : {
    "<GUID>" : { "content" : ... }
  }

}
```

It could be that in 0.0.2 the 'secret' model is no longer used, and so it would be nice if instead we could configure EmberFire to just store the `secret` objects as a child of `/versions/0_0_1/`:

```json
{
  "versions" : {
    "0_0_1" : {
      "isActive" : true,
      "secrets" : {
        "<GUID>" : { "content" : ... }
      }
    },
    "0_0_2" : {
      "isActive" : false
    }
  },
}
```

Ideally I want to configure my ember app to just treat the location `/versions/0_0_1/` as if it was the database root.

So as far as the app is concerned, the database consists only of:

```json
{
  "isActive" : true,
  "secrets" : {
    "<GUID>" : { "content" : ... }
  }
}
```

---

I understand that in production you really should only have one firebase database per version of the app if the object schema drastically changes, but unfortunately google only provides so many free databases to use, and so it would be nice when testing to be able to have multiple apps accessing the same database, just using different sub-paths.

When I tried changing `firebase.databaseURL` in `config/environment.js` from `<MyApp>.firebaseio.com/` to `<MyApp>.firebaseio.com/versions/0_0_1/` I get an error saying

> FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Database URL must point to the root of a
>   Firebase Database (not including a child path)

so I'm assuming this may not be not supported, at least via the `databaseURL` configuration option. Is there perhaps another option that could be used instead?

Alternatively, is there a way on a per-Model basis to configure a root path instead of a global one?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/6X3IP_aVHec

Comment: How did you solve this issue using Emberfire?